# Magento: Get Product Backordered Quantity in New Order Email

Tags: magento

I'm trying to add the number of backorder products to the email template that comes out in the new order email.

So far I've managed to get the product but I just can't seem to get it's quantity. I've tried a variety of methods but nothing seems to work. Here is my latest attempt:

The file is **app/design/frontend/base/default/template/email/order/items/order/default/phtml**

```
<?php 
    // 1. Get Qty of Product in Store. 
    // 2. Get Qty of product from order
    // 3. IF qty from order > qty in store then get number over
    // 4. Display number over

    $_sku = $this->getItem()->getSku();
    $_product = Mage::getModel('catalog/product')->loadByAttribute('sku', $_sku);
    //print_r($_product);
    echo 'qty in shop: '.$qtyInStock = $_product->getStockItem()->getQty(); //debugging
    echo 'qty ordered: '.$qtyOrdered = $_item->getQtyOrdered()*1; //debugging
?>

<?php if($qtyOrdered > $qtyInStock): $back_order = $qtyOrdered - $qtyInStock; ?>
    <p>* This product is not available in the requested quantity. <?php echo $back_order; ?> of the item(s) will be backordered.</p>
<?php endif; ?>
```

I'm not finished with the logic yet. I'm just stuck on getting the products quantity.

```
$_product->getStockItem()->getQty();
```

Any help most appreciated.

Billy

Answer (score 3):

Found a solution:

```
$_product = Mage::getModel('catalog/product')->loadByAttribute('sku', $_sku);
$stock_count = (int) Mage::getModel('cataloginventory/stock_item')->loadByProduct($_product)->getQty();
```

Seems quite roundabout but it does the job.

Feel free to suggest better...